# Flash VS Flex application

Tags: flash, apache-flex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flash versus Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812133/flash-versus-flex)

What are the main features that distinguish Flash from Flex?

When you have to create a web application, what do you look for select between Flash, Flex or using both?

Comment: Potential dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812133/flash-versus-flex

Comment: Yes I'm looking for a list similar to this, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you'll need to be more specific to actually compare two things.

Flash it a "generic" name around many of Adobe's tools and run times.  The Flash Player runs in the browser.  Flash Professional is an IDE for building Flash animations and graphics.  Flash Catalyst is an IDE for turning designer comps into FXG code.  Flash Builder is an IDE for building Flex (and ActionScript) applications.

Which Flash were you referring to?

Flex can refer to The Flex SDK, which is a group of tools for building Flash Applications.  It can be used to The Flex Framework which is a UI Framework.  It can also be used to refer to the Flex compiler which will turn ActionScript and MXML code into a Flash Application.  Flex could also refer to Flex builder, which is an IDE that has been renamed Flash Builder.

Which Flex were you referring to?

It might make sense to compare Flash Builder to Flash Professional, as they are both IDEs.  In that case, Flash Pro is geared more towards designers, timelines, and animation.  Flash Builder is more for programmers and is code centric.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the web site ur creating...!! We can integrate both of them or use either seperately..!!

Flash- provides animation and time line based development whereas flex has mxml language that has several components using which u can develop the complete web-site buttons,text box etc... It has well bulit programming construct as well as u can use action script if u wish to write custom components...!!

If u want more details tell me...

Answer (score 0):

Flex was created to provide a programmers interface to Flash.  Are you creating an animation/movie or are you creating an application?  Are you a programmer or do you have a flash background?

If it were me, I would use Flex.  Flex uses XML and ActionScript (an object oriented JavaScript language).  It is very easy to pick up, and quite capable.

Comment: actionscript based on ECMA standard, on which javascript is based too

Comment: Ankur's comment is correct.  It is the more accurate way of saying what I said.

Answer (score 0):

Flex is great for quickly building form heavy applications.  This is due to the great components that come with the sdk.  It's also easy to extend these out of the box components to make your own.

Flash is good for animation.

I always try to go with Flex because it produces cleaner code imo.  Plus, Flash Builder 4 is a much better editor than Flash Professional.