# Flex vs. Flash - which one?

Tags: flash, apache-flex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flash versus Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812133/flash-versus-flex)

Depending on the project size, which one do you like most--Flex or Flash?  Why do you like it more than the other?  What advantages does it have over the other?

Comment: What's the project?  Flex and Flash are geared toward different types of projects so an answer is gonna to depend on what you intend to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the type of your project and your coding style. If you come from a designer background or your project is highly visual (image processing, effects, timeframe manipulation) then Flash gives you more control.

On the other hand, if you prefer a programming IDE, Flex is a better choice. It's designed for programmers, not designers, so while the visual side will be more limited, you'll get a better coding experience.

In the end, you can do with both. You should choose based on your style.

Comment: hmmm...how much more "visual" is it?  do you know a good comparison on the internet?

Comment: You can program in an IDE while still writing a Flash project, though.  Just keep all code in AS files and compile with FlashDevelop, for example.  Also, you can use the Flex compiler without using the Flex framework.  *Not* using the framework is a very good idea if you're using the Flex compiler to make a game, even if you're just going to write it all in code... why bring in all the framework overhead?

Comment: this is a more comprehensive answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812133/flash-versus-flex